# Get text from image

Tags: python, image, pytesser

I need to use pytesseract to extract text from this picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwTV.png)

However, i used pytesseract. It wont work.Here is my code:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('1.png')))
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you get?

Comment: Make sure that you have downloaded tesseract and setup your system to run that properly. pytesseract depend on tesseract

Comment: Yes, i have downloaded tesseract and its running properly. Actually its printing nothing and sorry for said error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install [textract](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) using this we can extract text from any extension.

```
# some python file
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

you can provide `file` as image or pdf or any docs.
for your code

```
text = textract.process("1.png")
```